# Cypress- cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, rest, cypress

I have such a problem that cypress cannot find the properties. In response I get array. I want to find record and get CustomMessage. :)
Do you notice where I am making a mistake:/ ?
[image: console response]

[image: cypress error]

Here is my code :)

```js
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.body)
    .then((data) =>
      data.find((element) => element['body']['Message']['Phone'] == phone)
    )
    .then((phone) => (otpCode = phone['body']['Message']['CustomMessage']))
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is nothing in the array matches `phone`

Try adding a guard

```
cy.request(...)
  .then((resp) => resp.body)
  .then((data) => {
    const found = data.find((element) => element.body.Message.Phone === phone)
    if (!found) throw 'Error: phone not found'
    return found
  })
  .then((phone) => {
    otpCode = phone.body.Message.CustomMessage
  })
```

The way you have it originally, when `data.find()` fails the whole array is passed on to the `otpCode` extraction.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that solution, but I get error 'data.find is not a function' :/

Comment: The first then() needs to be added in...

Comment: BTW I forgot to add, you can "dot" the properties - will amend the code.

Comment: Maybe you will know how to resolve that problem 'cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined' ? :)
I pass value to 
getOtpCode(phoneNumber).then((otpCode) => {
            cy.get('input[data-placeholder="OTP"]').type(otpCode)
          })

Comment: Yes, if it was me I'd check the `phone` variable - it must be the same value in the data element `element.body.Message.Phone`.

Comment: Hmm, yes it is :) Method getOtpCode includes request above and has to returning otp code :)

Comment: Returning the `optCode` was handled in your previous question?

Comment: Actually yes, but no :D  There is a solution for another problem but after that new one appeared  :( (so I created new topic :) )

Comment: It's just you mention it in above comment - why was that?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misinterpreted the question. :/

Comment: Was just asking what you were asking on the comment "Hmm, yes it is..."

Comment: Aaa ok :) I wanted to respond to your question is the phone variable has the same value :) 
In test code I use method where i pass the phone number :) So I'm sure that the value is the same  in request :) I thought that this answer will tell you where I could have made a mistake :)

Comment: If you're sure the values are the same, then my answer is not right. I ran the test two times - 1) with correct phone and 2) with the wrong phone. First one succeeded, second one failed with exactly the same error you show in the question. So I presume the phone does not match any of  the response items.

Comment: Hmm, something must be wrong with the receiving value.
Because the method returns the message 'Phone not found' if I give a wrong number. Then the element must be found because found = true :/

Comment: `found` should never equal `true`, it should equal the item in the data array.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :)

Comment: You can still do `if (found) {}` when it's an item, doesn't have to be true/false.

Comment: Take a look at [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - ***If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.***

Comment: Your last comment helps me very much :).  I found the answer to my problem :) It is asynchronicity. 'return otpCode' must be in 'then()'.  Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the customMessage like this:

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'url',
}).then((resp) => {
  const customMessage = resp.body[1].body.Message.customMessage
})
```

Comment: Yes, I could. But I don't know which index contains an interesting property. I have to use the find method :)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple with [`cy-spok`](https://github.com/bahmutov/cy-spok).

```js
const 'spok' = require('cy-spok')


cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
  })
  // access properties with .its()
  .its('response.body')
  .its(1)
  .should(spok({
    Message: {
      Phone: spok.string // or us spok.test to check string length as well
    }
  // now we verified the response has Message.Phone let's extract it
  .its('Message.Phone')
  .as('otpCode')
```